# How can I use pipe in this code C++?

Tags: c++, ipc, pipe

I'm getting a big trouble because I dunno how to do this.
I need to create only 2 processes that can comunicate.
This is the code:

```
/* Wrappers */
this->sock_fd = this->w_socket();
this->w_bind();
this->w_listen();

std::cout << "[info] Server is running..." << std::endl;

while(1)
{
    /*Connection stuff */
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    int client_fd = this->w_accept(&client_addr);
    char client_ip[64];
    int client_port = ntohs(client_addr.sin_port);
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client_addr.sin_addr, client_ip, sizeof(client_ip));
    std::cout << "[info] Connection from (" << client_ip
        << ", " << client_port << ")" << std::endl;

    /*Login manager*/
    ...

    /* Crate PID */
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(this->sock_fd);
        this->manage(client_fd, client_ip, client_port);
        exit(0);
    }   
    /* End connection */
    close(client_fd);
}
```

Well. When a client is successfully authenticated after the login manager, can send data to the server.
If a client is connected and another one is logged in, the second have to kick the first client with a message "You have been disconnected".
How can I use fork and pipe to do that?
I've tried to read something on this, but I'm a bit confused about that.

Thank you.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGPIPE

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the specific design of your project but if you are using fork() to create a new client from an existing one and you want to use pipe() to communicate, here is a sample code.

```
int pfds[2];         //pipe() always return pair of file descriptors(fds).
char buf[30];

pipe(pfds);         //fds will be stored in pfds.

if (!fork()) {
    printf(" CHILD CLIENT: writing to pipe\n");
    write(pfds[1], "New Client", 11);
    printf(" CHILD CLIENT: exiting\n");
    exit(0);
} else {
    printf("PARENT CLIENT: reading from pipe\n");
    read(pfds[0], buf, 11);
    printf("PARENT CLIENT: read \"%s\"\n", buf);
    //Take appropriate Action upon read!!!
    wait(NULL);
}
```

I personally think there are better options than using pipes for this kind of communication(signals or shared memory).

Answer (score 0):

have a look at ZMQ: http://www.zeromq.org/